# Frontend joomla 2.5 menu login does not work

Tags: joomla2.5

I added a menu item of type "login form" to my main menu.
When it is pressed it brings me to an unknown page with the following error:

**An error has occurred.
The requested page cannot be found.
If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

## 404 Category not found**

My users, including myself, can not log in on the front end.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The menu type "Login Form" should not be able to create such an error, as there are no categories used in com_users.
Maybe double check that you correctly set the menu item to the needed type. Also you can turn off SEF URLs and check what URL is generated for the menu item. It should be like this:

> index.php?option=com_users&view=login

You can also this link yourself and it should bring you to the login form.

Also check if there are no modules enabled for this menu item which could generate this error.